Symlinks to /dev/ttyACM* behave differently than /dev/ttyACM* itself
I have a bunch of devices (about 20) connected to a usb hub on a remote server. These are dev ESP32 boards built into some prototype devices. The devices are tested on site (a small factory) during the day and connected back to the hub at night when I can read the logs form the devices and perform firmware updates. They show up in /dev as /dev/ttyACMn. As you might imagine having /dev/ttyACM0 to /dev/ttyACM18 is a mess. So I did something like this in udev rules:
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="303a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1001", PROGRAM="/etc/udev/rules.d/my-serial.sh" SYMLINK+="ttyESP32-%c

where my-serial.sh is:
serial_number=$(echo "$ID_SERIAL_SHORT" | tr -d ':')
modified_serial="${serial_number: -6}"
echo "$modified_serial"

So what it does, is it creates a symlink to the /dev/ttyACMx based on the device serial number - which practically speaking is the WiFi MAC address of the device. So now I have a practical way of differentiating between the devices. Instead of /dev/ttyACM0 (which might get enumerated in a random way), I use e.g. /dev/ttyESP32-C9A442
but...
The symlink doesn't behave the same as the original ttyACM0. Examples:

When typing "screen /dev/ttyESP32-C9A442" to connect to the terminal, bash does not autocomplete the device name. It does autocomplete /dev/ttyACM0. Both work as a expected.
The tools used for flashing the devices (esptool, pio) fail with an error: "Couldn't find a board on the selected port. Check that you have the correct port selected." when using /dev/ttyESP32-C9A442 but are fine with using /dev/ttyACM0.

So my question is: Is there a property of a file like /dev/ttyACM0 that does not carry on to its symlink? Since it causes issue both in bash terminal and with the specific tools, I'm guessing that they differ in some fundamental properties. Any idea how to fix this?
PS The /dev/ttyACM0 is owned by root:plugdev and the user is in the plugdev group. The symlink is (as default) owned by root:root, but even when using dereferenced chown to make it root:plugdev, makes no difference.
